# how to modify app.scss for bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.2 in laravel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I was using bootstrap-sass and I had this line to import bootrap styleshit in my app.scss:

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

Now I removed bootstrap-sass and I am using the 4.0.0 alpha2

How do I modify that line in app.scss?

This is the directory structure in node modules:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xAcuSfr.png]